# Props for creating a generic actor

Tags: scala, generics, akka, actor

Using

```
object TesterApp extends App {
  ...
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[User[Double]]), name = "user")
}
```

to create this actor:

```
class User[I: ClassTag] extends Actor {
  ...
}
```

gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
no matching constructor found on class com.test.User for arguments []
```

What is the correct way of creating such an actor?

Comment: Try this: `Props(new User[Double])` or this: `Props(classOf[User[Double]], implicitly[ClassTag[Double]])`.

Comment: Either alternative works, thanks!